# Callback issues in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I was playing around with callbacks and ran into this problem, unsure how related it is to callbacks, but I cant explain the result, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Why is the result: `'hi samsamsamsamsamsamsamsamsamsamsamsam'`,

I would expect: `'hi sam'`

---

```
function addSam(cb){
    var name = '';
    setTimeout(function(){
        name += 'sam';
        cb();
    }, 1000);
}

function speak(){
    console.log('hi ' + name);
}
```

When I call `addSam(speak)`,
The console returns:

`'hi samsamsamsamsamsamsamsamsamsamsamsam'`

Why does name += 'sam' happen multiple times?

How should I change the code so this only happens once and I can output simply:

`hi sam`

Comment: Your code will print only `"hi"`. I am damn sure

Comment: This is not possible, at least with code you posted. I pretty sure you have something else you are not posing here. Or you are missing `var name = '';` in your real code.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clear, I run: addSam(speak) at the end of this, this prints out 'hi samsamsamsamsamsamsamsamsamsamsamsam' in the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the variable `name` was defined inside `addSam` function, so it will only be accessible within that function and not globally.

If you want the function to output `hi sam` when it is called `addSam(speak)`, define `name` variable outside of the function so that it can be accessed globally. Like this:

```
var name = '';
function addSam(cb){
    setTimeout(function(){
        name += 'sam';
        cb();
    }, 1000);
}

function speak(){
    console.log('hi ' + name);
}

addSam(speak); // outputs 'hi sam' after a second
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function addSam(cb){
    var name = '';
    setTimeout(function(){
        name += 'sam';
        cb(name);
    }, 1000);
}

function speak(name){
    console.log('hi ' + name);
}
```